# Identify the parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, kinematics

I have the following parametrization in cylindrical coordinates:

$$R = 2, \quad \theta = \sin(t^2), \quad z = 2 \cos(t^2)$$

I know that it is the intersection of two perpendicular cylinders  $x^2 + z^2 = 4$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 4$. But that is because I've plotted it. What I wish to know is how to identify the parametrization, basically demonstrate that the parametrization is the intersection. I've tried going to standard basis but it gets very complicated.

Comment: You tagged this as "kinematics", can you share what kinematic problem led to this parametrization? This is definitely not the intersection of two perpendicular cylinders, except for small $t$ values.

Comment: The problem basically asks to describe the trajectory followed in the previous equations. Then work with the tangential and normal vectors. But my problem is that I can't show that the parametrization is the intersection. How do you know that the parametrizatio is not the intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: different curves]

On the left is the curve here. On the right is half the intersection of the two cylinders $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $x^2 + z^2 = 4$ (the other half is another circle of the same radius, but slanted 90 degrees to this one - I don't know how to convince Wolfram Alpha to plot both). As you can see, they are *not* the same curve.

Of course, since $R = 2$ always, this curve does lie on the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$. But if you project the other curve onto the $yz$ plane, you get this:

[image: flattened circle]

Note that while the vertical direction extends to $\pm 2$, the horizontal direction only extends to $\pm 2\sin 1 \approx 1.68$

If we convert the parametric equations from cylindrical to cartesian coordinates, we get $$(x,y,z) = (2\cos(\sin t^2), 2\sin (\sin t^2), 2\cos t^2)$$

If we project onto the $xy$ plane, we get $$(x,y) = (2\cos(\sin t^2), 2\sin (\sin t^2)) = 2(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$$where $\theta = \sin t^2$. Note that the points $2(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ lie on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$. But the angle $\theta$ is restricted to the range $-1$ to $1$ radians, since it is equal to the sine of another value. So this projection is one one side of the cylinder.

The projection onto the $xz$ plane is $(x,z) = (2\cos(\sin t^2),2\cos t^2)$ This shape looks similar to a parabola, but is not quite one. In addition to being somewhat mishappen, the values of $x$ are limited to $0$ to $2\sin 1 \approx = 1.68$.

So while your curve looks kind of like a circle drawn on a cylinder, it is not one.